# Search all columns in list of tables for particular string

Tags: table, sybase

I have a list of market data tables in one of our environments and need to search every column in the list for a certain string. Can anyone point me in the right direction.

```
1> select @@version
2> go
```

> Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.0.3/EBF 16558 ESD#1/P/Solaris AMD64/OS 5.10/

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to search for column *names*, or the *content* of the columns?

Comment: @MichaelO Your Sybase version is out of support. Please look into a possiblity of upgrading it to atleast Sybase 15.7 or 16.0 with latest Service Pack (EBF is not used anymore, Sybase now uses Service Pack)

Comment: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/c0c57332-8624-48c0-b4c3-5b31fe641c58 has code for Microsoft SQL Server. If you do not find a better answer, perhaps the code will help you work out a solution for your version of SyBase.

Answer (score 0):

You can query `syscolumns` and `sysobjects` in each database to get the information you need.

```
select 
  distinct so.name as TABLE_NAME,
  sc.name as COLUMN_NAME
from 
  syscolumns sc,
  sysobjects so
where 
  sc.id = so.id
and   sc.name like '%searchstring%'
order by so.name
```

If you need to limit your search to specific tables, then you can add an additional 'and' clause:

```
and so.name in ("Table1","Table2","Table3")
```

Comment: In Sybase does `master` contain the details on all `syscolumns` and `sysobjects` in the server?  That seems to be what your first sentence is describing.  Or does each database keep its own  `syscolumns` and `sysobjects` data?

Comment: @MichaelGardner The OP wants to search for a particular string in all the columns. Your answer searches for columns in tables. Please refer to my comment above, since this question is a dupe of the one that I referenced.

Comment: @MichaelGardner Its clear from the question - `need to search every column in the list for a certain string` --> So the OP is asking to search every column in the list for a particular string. **Also, your query has syntax error.** Did you try running it in sybase 15.0.3 instance ? It should be `SELECT so.name, sc.name as column_name 
FROM sysobjects so
INNER JOIN syscolumns sc ON so.id = sc.id 
where so.type = 'U'
and lower(sc.name) like '%test%'`

Comment: @kin Thanks for the correction, I was producing this from memory.  As for the OPs intention, I was not the only person to see ambiguity in the question, so I will continue to defer to the OP to clarify when he sees fit.